# Why can I not save my query result to csv file SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I'm beginner in SQL Server, and want to save query result auto in csv file.

This is the query:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "SELECT [ID]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[StartYear]
  FROM [dbo].[Employees]" queryout "e:\text.txt" -c -T -x
```

but get this error:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'bcp "SELECT [ID]
>             ,[FirstName]
>             ,[LastName]
>             ,[StartYear]
>         FROM [dbo].[Employees]" queryout "e:\text.txt" -c -T -x

What happened? How can I solve that?

I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000);

SET @sql = 'bcp "SELECT [ID]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[StartYear]
  FROM [dbo].[Employees]" queryout "e:\text.txt" -c -T -t, -S' + @@servername;

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql;
```

You need first to enable `xp_cmdshell`:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Keep in mind that enabling it may expose you to some type of attacks and you should avoid using it.

---

Alternatively if you need to do it once you can use `SSMS` -> `Tasks` -> `Export Data` -> `Flat File Destination`

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/01/sql-server-export-table-to-csv.html

Comment: thanks but now get this error:SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell'

Comment: ok great men,now dont get error,but dont save anything in file

Comment: @user3671271 Does your table contain any data?